# vi replace string and add a new line with some text

Tags: dns, bind, vi

I have multiple lines in a bind dns file zone with the same ip address. I need to replace that ip address and add a line below with another A record like this:

```
mail   IN    A    10.10.10.10
ftp    IN    A    10.10.10.10
```

After changes it should look like:

```
mail   IN    A    11.11.11.11
       IN    A    11.11.11.12
ftp    IN    A    11.11.11.11
       IN    A    11.11.11.12
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well edit it and do it then! What's the question?

Comment: There are lots of records.And I'd like to find a way how to search and replace  this...like :s/string/newstring/g,but also add a new line with an exstra A record. If there were just a couple of strings I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you want, I would do this:

1. Do a global substitute on the ip addresses:
   `:%s/0/1/g`
2. Do some macro-like action on the lines in question with the "global" command:
   `:g/\v(mail|ftp)/normal yypviwr $r2`

   This duplicates every line containing "mail" or "ftp", replaces the first word of the new line with spaces and finally, replaces its last char with "2".

See `:h :g` for more help on the "global" command.